# Faster than a showoff

Tags: riddle

> - Some think I'm fashionable and wear me.
> - Some say I'm slow, yet I'm faster than a showoff.
> - When I'm down, my friends tell me that I will eventually get back on my feet, but that's just cruel.
> - Sometimes I dress up like those sneaky Japanese.
> - I might be robust and durable, but I tend to not stick my neck out unless I really have to.

Who am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a:

> Turtle/ Tortoise (I know they are different but bear with me)

Some think I'm fashionable and wear me

> Turtleneck sweaters and turtleshell spectacle rims

Some say I'm slow yet I'm faster than a showoff

> The turtle and the hare (technically tortoise)

When I'm down, my friends tell me that I will eventually get back on my feet, but that's just cruel

> A tortoise upended onto its shell has a lot of difficulty getting back onto its feet, and leaving one in that position is rather cruel

Sometimes I dress up like those sneaky Japanese

> Ninjas as in TMNT (Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles)

I might be robust and durable, but I tend to not stick my neck out unless I really have to

> self-explanatory

Comment: Too easy was it? Just one hint to go! Maybe it will be hard to find if you are young. Not sure.

Comment: Perhaps Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles, for clue #4

Comment: @tmpearce: thanks, boboquack also added that to my answer. :)